# Object not found when trying to get image url in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm trying to make a system to send urls from images taken by the camera in a flutter app. This code is from a widget to send the link to the main messaging page, and it is all under an onPressed for an upload button. imagePath and such all work properly, and there are no errors.

```
var file=File(imagePath);
var fileName="photo-"+DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()+".jpg";
var ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("photos").child(fileName);
ref.putFile(file);
printUrl() async {
  String url = (await ref.getDownloadURL()).toString();
  print(url);
  Navigator.pop(context, url.toString());
}
printUrl();
```

When the button is pressed, there is a multitude of errors

```
W/StorageUtil( 5602): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
W/StorageUtil( 5602): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
W/StorageUtil( 5602): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
E/StorageException( 5602): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException( 5602): Object does not exist at location.
E/StorageException( 5602):  Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException( 5602): {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
E/StorageException( 5602): java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
E/StorageException( 5602):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:445)
E/StorageException( 5602):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:462)
E/StorageException( 5602):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:453)
E/StorageException( 5602):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
E/StorageException( 5602):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:289)
E/StorageException( 5602):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:76)
E/StorageException( 5602):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:68)
E/StorageException( 5602):  at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(GetDownloadUrlTask.java:77)
E/StorageException( 5602):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/StorageException( 5602):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/StorageException( 5602):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/flutter ( 5602): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.
E/flutter ( 5602): #0      MethodChannelReference.getDownloadURL (package:firebase_storage_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_reference.dart:59:7)
E/flutter ( 5602): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5602): #1      DisplayPictureScreen.build.<anonymous closure>.printUrl (package:historyscope/takePicture.dart:139:31)
E/flutter ( 5602): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5602):
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this? From the messages, it seems that flutter is unable to get the URL(and putting in print statements confirms that this the line with the getDownloadURL is the one that does not work). However I don't know how to fix, since the images are being uploaded to Firebase Storage.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading the file happens asynchronously, and a download URL can only be generated after the upload has completed.

```
var ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("photos").child(fileName);
await ref.putFile(file); //  Add await here
String url = (await ref.getDownloadURL()).toString();
print(url);
Navigator.pop(context, url.toString());
```